# this.val not working in JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$('.free-gifts').on("click",".free-gift-item", function() {

    console.log(this.val());

});
```

This is my code and this gets returned when I write only 'this' in console.log.:

```
<img class="free-gift-item" value="Vaucet1" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1158/4752/t/2/assets/Vaucet1.jpg?11031098756291991926">
```

Maybe .value works with $ only. Then what logic should be used?

Comment: You need to use: `$(this).attr('value');`

Comment: But when I do this, it says $this not defined.

Comment: Please post this as an answer :) It actually worked for me. I was using $this.attr but instead I had to use $(this).attr. please explain a little bit in your answer so it helps other people too :)

Comment: posted. glad to help

Comment: Images don't have value attributes. You should be using a custom data attribute instead. Ex: `data-value="Vaucet1"`

Comment: Then what do you suggest? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since images can't have value attributes (invalid HTML), you should instead be using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to assign arbitrary data to an element.

```
<img class="free-gift-item" data-value="Vaucet1" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1158/4752/t/2/assets/Vaucet1.jpg?11031098756291991926">
```

Then retrieve the value with jQuery's [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```
$('.free-gifts').on("click",".free-gift-item", function() {
    console.log($(this).data('value'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this :)